# Getting UI Element that has keyboardFocus from itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, itemscontrol

I have a itemscontrol that displays some textboxes dependning on the observable collection items in viewmodel. I need to determine the textbox that has keyboard focus on click of a button outside the itemscontrol.

Problem:
1. When i click the button the keyboard focus shifts to button instead of the textbox. 
2. How can i get the a ui element that has keyboard focus inside the itemscontrol.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use logical focus and a focus scope inside the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="_itemsControl" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true"/>
```

Then, in your code behind:

```
var focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(_itemsControl);
```